# Use object parameter or no parameters for functions?

Tags: c++

When creating a function for a class, should the parameter take a pointer to the class type and be invoked using 'this', or create a parameterless function and call it normally. Here is a demonstration:

```
class ExampleOne {

   ExampleOne::ExampleOne() {
      performAction(this);
   }


   void ExampleOne::performAction(ExampleOne *obj)
   {
      // Do something
   }

}


class ExampleTwo {

   ExampleTwo::ExampleTwo() {
      performAction();
   }

   void ExampleTwo::performAction()
   {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

In ExampleOne, the class functions are called with a pointer reference to itself. In ExampleTwo, functions are called without parameters.

I have seen both methods used in c++ code, and do not know which is the correct programming method.

The same question applies to working with the global instance variables, like this:

```
class ExampleThree {
   ExampleThree::ExampleThree() {
      Object *obj = new Object;

      someFunction(obj);
   }

   ExampleThree::someFunction(Object *obj) {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

Or do we work with the instance variables rather than pointers to it:

```
class ExampleFour {
   ExampleFour::ExampleFour() {
      Object *obj = new Object;

      someFunction();
   }

   ExampleFour::someFunction() {
      // Do something with Obj instance
   }
}
```

Comment: In your first example is the parameter to performAction supposed to be of type ExampleOne? It says "Example *obj" and you don't describe what type Example is supposed to represent.

Comment: Small mistake, now corrected in question.

Comment: I don't know of any benefit of the first one, maybe it was an implementation done by a python programmer? Or the method is `static` so you there is no instance?

Comment: Unless you want to be able to work on other instances of `ExampleOne` that seems redundant and pointless.

Comment: And for ExampleThree, is this correct, or do we continue to use parameterless functions and call these functions and call the instance from inside the function?

Comment: You can't use obj in ExampleFour, as its a local object.

Comment: This is more of a design question than a coding question. I suspect you will find examples where one approach makes sense and will find other examples where the other approach makes sense.

Comment: The reason this is done is code reuse, when some work done in the constructor can be used in other functions, if it can't then you should not make a separate function. And you shouldn't make the reuse function before there is a need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is done is code reuse, when some work done in the constructor can be used in other functions, if it can't then you should not make a separate function. And you shouldn't make the reuse function before there is a need.

The C++03 way

```
A {
  A() {
    Common(42);
  }
  A(int a) {
    Common(a);
  }
  void Common(int c) {
    ... do something really complicated with c
  }
}
```

The C++11 way

```
A {
  A() : A(42) {  // you can now call other constructors.
  }
  A(int a) {
    ... do something really complicated with c
  }
}
```

Also in C++11 the move constructor and move assignment function mostly shares the same code (the latter has a return also) which could be reused.

The preferred way is to do everything in the initializer list for the constructor, which makes everything more safe. And only do something in the body if really needed.

```
C {
  int dc;
  C(int c) : dc(c) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write something like this

```
MyClass myObject;
myObject.someFunction();
```

`myObject` is implicitly passed by reference to `MyClass::someFunction`, so you can access its attributes or methods by their names, without using the keyword `this`.

The usual way to use `this` is when you actually need a pointer or a reference to your object. For example, it is common when you overload `operator=()` to make it return a reference to the object with `return *this;`